# Unity: Index was outside the bounds of the Array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im developing with Unity for about a year now and very often I got this Error:
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
I know that that error means that the given index is bigger then the array itself. But I dont think that the Array is bigger than the used value.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProceduralGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[3000, 3000];
public GameObject[] prefabs;
int sizeyet = 0;
GameObject obj;
public int renderdistance;

int[,] map;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    map = CreateMap(map);
    for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.Length; j++)
        {
            
            
            obj = Instantiate(prefabs[map[i,j]], new Vector2(i, j), Quaternion.identity);
            tiles[i, j] = obj;

            
        } 
    }
}

public int[,] CreateMap(int[,] map)
{
    map = new int[4000, 4000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3000 - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i < 3000 - 1; j++)
        {
            map[i, j] = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise(i, j) * 10);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
```

}

I very often canceled project because I couldn't fix this error.

If my English is not so good, excuse me. Im a german student.

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Aside from the rest - is there a reason you've declared `obj` as a field? You only appear to be using it in the `Start` method - I'd declare it as a local variable in the most nested loop in there.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems here. Firstly, there's a typo in `CreateMap`:

```cs
for(int j = 0; i < 3000 - 1; j++)
```

Note how you're using `i` in the condition instead of `j` - so that loop will never terminate, assuming that `i` is less than 2999 to start with. But even changing that won't fix the bigger problem. Let's look at the rest of the code.

Here's how you initialize `map`:

```cs
map = new int[4000, 4000];
```

And here's how you initialize `tiles`:

```cs
public GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[3000, 3000];
```

So `map.Length` is 16000000, because that's the *total size of the array*.

Now let's look at your loop:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < map.Length; j++)
    {
        obj = /* irrelevant */
        tiles[i, j] = obj;
    } 
}
```

So your code is a *bit* like this:

```cs
GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[3000, 3000];
for (int i = 0; i < 16000000; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 16000000; j++)
    {
        tiles[i, j] = something;
    }
}
```

Can you see how that's *clearly* going to go way out of bounds?

Even if the code behaved as you expected it to, `tiles` is 3000x3000 and `map` is 4000x4000, so that would be a problem.

I suggest you create some constants, and use those everywhere:

```cs
private const int MapWidth = 4000;
private const int MapHeight = 4000;

public GameObject[,] tiles = new GameObject[MapWidth, MapHeight];
...

// Then later...
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MapHeight; j++)
    {
        tiles[i, j] = ...;
    }
}

// And in CreateMap:
map = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MapHeight; j++)
    {
        map[i, j] = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise(i, j) * 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I watched at my other games and that was everywhere the error. That was a very stupid mistake. That really really helps me!